# mongodb: how to multiply a field by a constant in an if else branket

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have a runningPnL field and description field as well as a date field.
I want to do:
if the description is "Breakup" then multipliedPnL=2*runningPnL
otherwise multipliedPnL=runningPnL
my code is:

```
 db.getCollection('user0').aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project:
           {
             thedate: 1,

             realPnL:
               {
                 $cond: { if: { $gte: [ "$description", "Breakup" ] }, then: {$multiply:[$runningPnL,2]}, else: $runningPnL}
               }
           }
      }
   ]
)
```

Theres a reference error : runningPnL not defined.
WHats wrong with my code?
thx a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the field variables in quotes, e.g. the part `then: { "$multiply": [ "$runningPnL", 2] }, else: "$runningPnL"`?

Comment: you need to show us your sample document (collection data) to see where the "runningPnL" is residing. I think this will tell us how to get to "runningPnl". But your code looks correct.

Comment: haha that works! thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try $mul? What is your mongodb version?

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/

An example for the documentation is like this

```
db.products.update(
 { _id: 1 },
 { $mul: { price: 1.25 } }
)
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question, the OP wants to project the field on a given condition, not to update the collection.